# What would be the best step to take for a 21-year-old who really wants to travel but doesn’t have enough money?

Tags: budget

What would be the best step to take for a 21-year-old who really wants to travel but doesn’t have enough money?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by travelling? Where do you live?

Comment: depending on your nationality there may also be working holiday visa options

Comment: You can start by walking to a near town or village and beg a place to sleep from a friend or relative, walking home the next day. After you have done some of those you may go for longer walks, find places to sleep safely in the wild or getting places to sleep from say farmers in exchange for some work. No money needed even for weeks, as long as you disregard food which you would need at home as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best step to take would be find a job and save your money. Those are within your control unlike other options such as playing the lottery.

Comment: And there are jobs that can let you accomplish both: crew on airlines and cruise ships.

Comment: Including travel blogger et al. I wasn’t inclined to bother with adding all that.